# How to add a folder in a secondary tab?

Tags: customization, app-drawer, nova-launcher

I'm using Nova Launcher Prime v4.2.2 on my stock and rooted Android 6.0.1. I intend to create folders in secondary tabs under app drawer. Whenever I create a folder entry through Nova Settings → App & widget drawers → Drawer groups → Folders, the folder gets created only in the primary tab<sup><sup>*</sup></sup>.  Changing the order of tabs under Tabs setting and then creating a new folder doesn't work. The folder always ends up in primary tab.

In the app drawer, attempting to drag the folder minimizes the app drawer and throws user back to home screen with option to place the folder there, just like how an app shortcut is placed.

I noticed an entry for my folder in the table *drawer_groups* of database *launcher.db* located at */data/data/com.teslacoilsw.launcher/databases/*. Force stopping the launcher, switching the default launcher and making few changes in that table for that folder didn't help either.

So, how do I add a folder into a non-primary tab under app drawer?

---

<sup><sup>*</sup></sup> <sub>By primary tab I mean the only tab which offers the option to hide apps.</sub>

Comment: Looking for this too, haven't had any luck yet. :(

Answer (score 4):

Edit the folder from within the app drawer as if you were editing an app.  (Long press the folder and drag it to the "Edit" option at the top).

From there you can check/uncheck which tab(s) you wish for it to appear in.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while. Thank you very much.